# Issue while populating array in COBOL

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am getting very strange scenario. I have one array defined in my COBOL pgm.

```
05  A-TABLE.                                   
    10  A-TABLE-LIST OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY A-IDX. 

        15  FILLER              PIC X(7) VALUE '<TEST>'. 
        15  A-LIST-VALUE        PIC X(30).                
        15  FILLER              PIC X(8) VALUE '</TEST>'.
```

I am setting A-IDX=1 and moving 'XYZ' to A-LIST-VALUE(A-IDX).
While displaying A-TABLE, it is showing as 
XYZ------------------------------
and all spaces... :(
I am not getting what is the issue here?
Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Regards,
Saisha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set values for a table that way.  One way to set values in a table is to use a REDEFINES and a separate data area.

```
05  A-TABLE-X.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.
    10  FILLER PIC X(45)
        VALUE '<TEST>                              </TEST>'.

05  A-TABLE REDEFINES A-TABLE-X.     
    10  A-TABLE-LIST OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY A-IDX. 

        15  FILLER              PIC X(7). 
        15  A-LIST-VALUE        PIC X(30).                
        15  FILLER              PIC X(8).
```

That is pretty cumbersome.  Another method is to MOVE the data in at runtime in an initialisation paragraph.

```
05  A-TABLE REDEFINES A-TABLE-X.     
    10  A-TABLE-LIST OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY A-IDX. 

        15  A-LIST-A            PIC X(7). 
        15  A-LIST-VALUE        PIC X(30).                
        15  A-LIST-B            PIC X(8).

PERFORM VARYING A-IDX FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL A-IDX > 1
  MOVE '<TEST> TO A-LIST-A(A-IDX)
  MOVE SPACES TO A-LIST-VALUE(A-IDX)
  MOVE '</TEST> TO A-LIST-B(A-IDX)
END-PERFORM
```

I didn't try compiling any of these, this is just freehand.

As a side note, if you are using Enterprise COBOL version 3.2 or higher and you are trying to create XML in COBOL, there exists an XML GENERATE statement.

Comment: I dont think problem is with the way the array index has been setting up. Its problem with moving... dont u think so?

Comment: I agree, the problem isn't with the array index. I think the problem is with the VALUE clauses on a table entry.  That sort of initialization doesn't work, and I'm surprised it didn't produce a compile error.

Comment: because, the value was present for FILLER, i believe

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, your question is why "XYZ<27 spaces>" is being displayed when only "XYZ" was moved. If so, you need to `initialize` before moving and `trim` the spaces before displaying or moving into another variable.

If your problem is not yet solved, describe much otherwise let us know how it was resolved.